# I/flutter (23942): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]

Tags: flutter, dart, http-error, dio

I'm facing HTTP error 500 while Authenticating or log in with API.
and Unable to get this error.
it was working nicely before but suddenly throwing me this HTTP error.

**CODE:**

The instance of Dio class:

```
dio() {
    Dio dio = Dio();

    dio.options.connectTimeout = 60000; //5s
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 60000;
    return dio;
  }
```

authenticating method:

```
Future<Map> authenticate({@required String username, @required String password}) async{
   String url =  "https://.....";
   Response response;
   try{
     response =await dio().post(
       url,
       options: Options(
         contentType: ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
       ),

       data: {
         'grant_type': 'password',
         'client_id':clientId,
         'client_secret':clientSecret,
         'username': username,
         'password': password,
       }
     );
     print("Authentication post response.dataaaaaa:${response.data}");
     return response.data;

   }catch(e){
     print("ERROR:$e");
     throw e;
   }
 }
```

Getting error in catch bloc:

```
 DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]
```

Comment: The server returned status code 500, which basically means "server error". If you do not, experiment with something like Postman until you are able to get a successful response, then adapt your code to match.

Answer (score 2):

Http status code 500 means something wrong from your API backend?

Comment: Yes, from my point of view.
But you should add your URL into Dio configuration. 
For example: `client.options.baseUrl = BASE_URL`